# Gridview clear selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've a condition in a gridview where I've to clear in the gridview selection when one of the selectIndexChanging event happens

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some logic

    //some condition
    {
        Gridview1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

But the index is not getting cleared in this case in that given condition. Any suggestions on why this might not be working ? Thanks

Comment: You have to call `DataBind()` after changing a GridView property.

Comment: That still did not work. Is there any other way  to clear selection in the gridview ?

Comment: Clearing the selected index while making a row selection within the same gridview seems wrong. what is the criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, not the `SelectedIndexChanging` event.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = mySource;
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Gridview.SelectedIndex = -1 does not work in SelectedIndexChanging. I used selectIndexChanged instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel selection, then just set

```
e.Cancel=true;
```

So the pervious selection will remain.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewselecteventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for this but I had a different requirement and no previous selection should appear as well